# "These credentials do not authorize access" (403)

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to make a request to "HERE On-Street Parking API" from a Freemium account. I already got  my bearer token successfully. I use the token in my request but I got the following:
`{ "error": "Forbidden", "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access" }`
The URL to where we are trying to make the request is:
https://osp.cit.cc.api.here.com/parking/segments?bbox=41.389405513925354,2.127549994463742,41.38042236108416,2.139522979169079&datetime=2019-01-21T09:42:10Z

Comment: Why do you assume that the error message is not correct? (These credentials do not authorize access))

Comment: I'm assumming it because I already talk with the marketing support (thinking that I need an enterprise plan) and they told me that maybe it's a tech problem because I should have access to that api on a freemium account.

Comment: Do you think that I get that error because I cannot do that call with a freemium account?

Comment: Have you tried putting in your API key? https://osp.cit.cc.api.here.com/parking/segments?bbox=41.389405513925354,2.127549994463742,41.38042236108416,2.139522979169079&datetime=2019-01-21T09:42:10Z&apiKey={{API_KEY}}

Comment: Yes I already tried adding the API key as a parameter (api_key={API_KEY} or apiKey={API_KEY}) but I got the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-Street Parking is not part of the Freemium plan, so that message is correct.

Comment: So, which plan contain On-Street Parking API? And where we can get a list of supported countries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the "contact us" form on the developer portal to reach out to a HERE representative for more information on accessing this API.

Comment: is this mentioned anywhere in heremaps docs which API require more than freemium? I'm having same problem with https://ev-v2.cit.cc.api.here.com/ev/stations.json